# Difference between limit point and sequential limit point.

Tags: general-topology

I got a question from online. To check whether a point is limit point of a subspace of Hausdorff space, then that point is a sequential limit point.

But the term "Sequential limit point" is new to me. I searched online, couldn't find. I found the question in the site. But definition is missing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: A point $x$ is a sequential limit point of a set $A$ if there is a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$.

Comment: that's the definition of limit point too, right? What's the difference?

Comment: No, it’s not the definition of a limit point of $A$: $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if every open nbhd of $x$ contains at least one point of $A\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: Through the definition of limit point, we can extract a sequence which converges to $x$ right?

Comment: How it differs? Can you give a counter please?

Comment: No: there may not be **any** non-trivial sequences that converge to $x$. Let $X$ be an uncountable set with the co-countable topology; for any $x\in X$, a sequence $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ if and only if there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n=x$ for all $n\ge m$. Let $A=X\setminus\{x\}$; the $x$ is a limit point of $A$, but there is no sequence in $A$ converging to $x$.

Comment: OKay. Makes sense.